# How to make two different button for open file from selecting data in PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
include("connect.php");
mysqli_query($link,"set NAMES utf8");
$code=@$_POST['code'];
$select="SELECT * FROM subject_teachers WHERE code='$code'";

$result=mysqli_query($link,$select) or die(mysqli_error($link));

 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<button value='$row[subject]'>".$row['subject'];
}
?>
```

[image]

I have selected two value(word&excel)from database, I want to when click each one of value and button open different file, how I can?

Comment: You're wide open to [SQL Injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenate your queries. Specially since you're not even escaping the user inputs.

Comment: What do you call "values" from database ? What is it ? blob ? file url ? relative path to your file ? Give at least examples

Comment: In this code:
<?php
include("connect.php");
$code=@$_POST['code'];
$select="SELECT * FROM subject_teachers WHERE code='$code'";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$select) or die(mysqli_error($link));
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo $row['subject'];
}
?>

When i run this code appear the value in the browser that stored from data base for example (Word , Excel, PHP),
I wan to these value make a link when click each one of them open file from my project in www directory in the wampserver. for example word.php, excel.php etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking...

```
<a href="<?php echo $row['url_word_file'] ; ?>">Word file</a>
<a href="<?php echo $row['url_excel_file'] ; ?>">Excel file</a>
```

Comment: this value(word &excel) is two record in my database selected, I want to when click word button open a (word.php)file in my directory and when click excel button open (excel.php), are you understand?

Comment: You're saying that the whole excel and word files are stored in DB ? in blob ?

Comment: Not saved in my database but this file saved in my WampServer www diretcory.

Comment: So you just have to make a link to your stored files... ?

Comment: yes I want to make files to link, do you have any solution?

Comment: Yeah... in my answer ? What is stored in your DB ? paths to your files ? so just make a link to them !

Comment: the value stored in my database only name of subjects(word,excel)but files I want to open stored in www.

Comment: In this code: <?php include("connect.php"); $code=@$_POST['code']; $select="SELECT * FROM subject_teachers WHERE code='$code'"; $result=mysqli_query($link,$select) or die(mysqli_error($link)); while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo $row['subject']; } ?> When i run this code appear the value in the browser that stored from data base for example (Word , Excel, PHP), I wan to these value make a link when click each one of them open file from my project in www directory in the wampserver. for example word.php, excel.php etc...

Comment: For the last time : give us an example of what there is $row['subject']. WHAT is it ??? path ? filename ? I'm not stupid i know that if you echo $row['subject'] it echo the value !! but what is this value ?

Comment: subject is the name of the filed from my table in the database that stored subject (word,excel).

Comment: Where is stored your file ? give us a path example.
AND give us an EXAMPLE of what there is in $row['subject']. There is something that can help to find the file, right ? His name ? His path ? You're not really saying that when you echo $row['subject'], it display "word" or "excel" ? You have a filename or a path somewhere in that DB, right ??

Comment: Mr. Pierre Granger Iam so sorry you write, but i understand you but I can't speak English very well sorry,

my files stored is(E:\wamp\www\Projefct Exam),
$row['subject'] his name, i want to clicked to open an other file,it is display all data stored on my table,
I have a table name subject contain some of fields (id,name,subject).

Comment: <a href="./Project Exam/<?php echo $row['subject'] ; ?>">Word file</a> assuming $row['subject'] contain your file name (ex: my-doc.doc) so it will write href="./Project Exam/my-doc.doc". But i still don't understand if there is the file name in $row['subject'] as you don't provide an example, so i can't help you anymore. I was just asking for an EXAMPLE of what you store in your table.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Pierre Granger :) .

Comment: Does it solved your problem ? Please consider to mark the answer checked so next users should use the answer.

Comment: In the real my problem don't solved, Sorry for disturbing you, I updated my code in the question above, know you can see to understand $row['subject'] , that is used to get data from a row subject in the table in my database.

Comment: What it contains ?

Comment: Show the content of /Project_exam/ (file names), ans show thé content of your SQL table subjective_teachers. Thé datas, not the structure. Make an SQL export if you want.

Comment: Mr. Pierre Granger, can you send me your email to send my project to you, to check my problem and understand my idea, Tank you very much.

Comment: Sorry I can't, questions and answers has to be on stackoverflow as it is an helping site who is supposed to help not only you but also people which have the same problem, so they can see the whole solution.

Comment: Not a problem, you can just send it on a wetransfer and put the link here. But tou can just, as i ask you since days, send list of files in /Project_exam/ and export of your database. The only thing i need is how to know from a row i database where is the corresponding file... I just ask you for example of what your database contains since... days...